# How to slider in CClayer?

Tags: ipad, cclayer

I have to add one slider in CCLayer. How to make slider. I went through online and I got there is one object t but which is available in UISlider. If I am implementing it then how will I add it into cclayer?

I m making a small test game for iPad. It needs slide bar for volume control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/hiepnd/CCSlider !

There is info how to add it, too.

Found in http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14329 .